# ajax not returning to php index page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

pleae note that i m trying jump to test.php page from index.php/html using ajax and mysql, simple if text-input not found in table so it should go to test.php else stay on index.php/html page with ajax alerts, but from index page everytime receiving NOT AVAILABLE and sometime submit button not functional, below code FYR...

```
//index.php $(document).ready(function() {
            //default form not submitted
             $("#submit").data("submitted",false);    
            //preventing enter key in input field from submitting form
            $("#welcome").on("submit", function(e){
                if($('#submit').data("submitted")===false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
             //trigger form submission
            $("#submit").on("click",function(){
            validate();
            });});
//default form not submitted                
//$("#submit            
function validate() {
                var num = $('#invst_num').val();
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check_test.php',
                data: num,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                        if(data){
                            alert("NOT AVAILABLE");
                        } else {
                            $("#submit").data("submitted", true);
                            $("#welcome").submit();
                            }
                        }}</script> <form action="check_test.php" method="post" name="welcome" id="welcome" /> <table width="550" border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>   <tr>
<td align="center"><label>
  Enter Inv. # *: 
    <input name="invst_num" type="text" id="invst_num" size="40"  /> 
  <input name="submit" type='submit' id='submit' />  </label></td>  </tr></table> </form>

//check_test.php <?php 
include ("config/config.php");
//get the username
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$invst_num = $_POST['invst_num'];
//mysql query to select field username if it's equal to the username that we check '
$sql = mysql_query("select invst_num_ar from shareholders_ar where invst_num_ar =  '$invst_num' "); 
if ($result = mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) {
    echo ($result);
    }
}
?>
// if not found...test.php should load
<html>
<form 
...
Register Data
/form>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional is backwards

```
if(data){
```

Should be

```
if(!data){
```

Or the alert should be flipped with the listener adding logic.

Comment: Thanks lwnnay :) I am wondering that changing of condition statement to 'if(!data){' but while compiling dev tool showing the prevent function warning and form goes to next **index.php** page when twice clicked submit button without alert if statement false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var num = $('#invst_num').val();
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'check_test.php',
       data: num,
```

ajax call is sending value frome `data` key, so you send only the text field content.

You probably should send sth like this:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'check_test.php',
       data: { 'invst_num': num },
 ...
```

Open Dev tools in your browser and check what content is being sent during ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have changed 'data' also and now still popup alert not allowing to go index page, further i noted that while clicking submit button DEV Tool showing the below two warning messages

Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:4:0

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:2:8283

Comment: As @Iwnnay said the condition is 4sure wrong - you are waiting to receive data but if you get it sending an alert. Few notices from my site: Use http response codes to indicate if anything is wrong, so in this case 200 is ok, 400 something wrong. Validate it in js relying on this. For more info look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)
You still dodn't wrote what data is being posted and what the response is - in your dev tools enable sth like "preserve logs" and check what is really happening,